# Is there a way to automate restarting with a different boot disk?

Tags: automator, startup, restart

I have Lion and Snow Leopard installed on my machine, and I switch between them all the time (I develop for compatibility on both platforms). Going into System Preferences and selecting the startup disk every time is quite a pain, it would be great if I could automate this process with a script that I can launch from my dock.

Comment: Note that although it wouldn't fit your question title of "automate" you can hold the option key immediately after the boot chime to see all the accessible bootable mediums and choose the OS you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo bless -mount /Volumes/"startup disk name" -setBoot`

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`reboot`

This should work.

Comment: Saved as a bash script this fits my needs perfectly.